# NumberFormatException resulting from java conversion

Tags: java, binary, numberformatexception, parseint

The goal is to convert a String to int in java.

My declarations:

```
String [] dataIn = new String[100];
int [] binVals = new int[100];
int i;
String toBinary;
```

I first convert a hex string to a binary string.

```
static String hexToBin(String s) {
        return new BigInteger(s,16).toString(2);
    }
.....
.....
toBinary = hexToBin(dataIn[i]);

try{
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(toBinary); 
    binVals[i] = temp;
    System.out.println(temp);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Not gonna work");
}
```

toBinary is a String value of 32 bits i.e. 00011100...01
I printed the result to the console to make sure it is valid for an integer conversion. Yet, using  `Integer.parseInt(toBinary);`  still throws the exception. What am I missing here?

**Updated**

According to what you guys said, I now no longer receive an exception, but when I convert the binary String into an integer, it seems to become a decimal integer.

```
if (i % 2 == 0)
{
toBinary = hexToBin(dataIn[i]); 
System.out.println("Binary in String: " + toBinary);
try{
    int temp = Integer.parseInt(toBinary, 2); 
    binVals[i] = temp;
    System.out.println("binVals[i] in int" + binVals[i]);
} catch (NumberFormatException ex){
    System.out.println("Not gonna work");
}
    //System.out.println(temp);
} else {
    System.out.println("This should be a timestamp: " + dataIn[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
Binary in String: 1001010101010101010101010100000
binVals[i] in int1252698784
This should be a timestamp: 2068a40
```

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(toBinary, 2);` to again have the same integer. Though if the sign bit is set (negative number) you indeed better use `(int)Long.parseLong(..., 2)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `Integer.parseInt` without a radix will interpret the string as a decimal number, not binary.  Most such "binary" strings will represent numbers that are over the maximum integer possible, a little over 2 billion, e.g. 111,000,101,010,001.

Pass in a radix of 2 (binary) to [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-int-):

```
int temp = Integer.parseInt(toBinary, 2);
```

However, if the first "bit" is set, then the represented number will be over `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, and then only `Long.parseLong` will work.

Comment: Thanks, the exception is gone. Although another issue has popped up, I have updated the question

Comment: The number in an `int` isn't in any format.  Only when `println` converts it to a `String` is the decimal representation created - `1252698784`.  Are you trying to convert it back to hex as part of your test?

Comment: I would like to keep it as a binary number

Comment: Use [`Integer.toString(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-), passing a radix of `2` as the second argument, to convert it to a string that is a binary representation of the number.

Comment: Ok my understanding is that if I want binary representation, it needs to stay as a String as I already have done and not an integer?

Comment: To display any numeric value, you need to convert it to a `String`, whether you are doing so implicitly or explicitly.  With `Integer.toString(int, int)`, you are explicitly choosing how you want your `int` to be represented as a `String`.

Comment: Understood. You answered my original question and resolved my confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try `Integer.parseInt(toBinary, 2);`. the 2 specifies that the string is in binary (base **2**)

Edit: for your new issue, the problem is that Java will by default print integers as decimal, so you need to turn your (decimal) integer back into a binary string. You can use `Integer.toBinaryString(int i)` for this.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I have updated the question as the integer is no longer in binary now

Answer (score 0):

For parsing and formatting integers you should consider using `BigInteger`.

Converting to String in any radix use [BigInteger.toString(int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toString%28int%29).

For parsing use [new BigInteger(String s, int radix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29).